# How to prevent rerunning a rule when input files have been updated by snakemake?

Tags: python, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have the following snakemake workflow that sequentially generates 3 files (a, b and c)

```
rule all:
    input:
        ['a'],
        ['b'],
        ['c'],
     
rule a:
    output: "a"
    shell: "touch {output}"

rule b:
    input: "a"
    output: "b"
    shell: "touch {output}"

rule c:
    input: "b"
    output: "c"
    shell: "touch {output}"
```

if I delete the file 'b' and rerun the workflow `rule c` is also rerun because:

`reason: Input files updated by another job: b`

Is there a way to prevent `rule c` from being rerun and only run `rule b`?

I have tried using `ancient`:

```
rule c:
    input: ancient("b")
    output: "c"
    shell: "touch {output}"
```

as well as using the `--rerun-triggers` argument to only rerun on code changes

`snakemake -s ./test_simple.smk --cores --rerun-triggers code`

but `rule c` is still rerun.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--until` option, for example to run everything until `rule c`:

```bash
snakemake -j 1 --until c
```

(`-j` flag is to specify one core, but using `--cores` will also work)

Comment: Thanks, the situation I am running into is a bit more complex and I don’t know ahead of time which rule to stop at, for example, in some cases file ‘a’ might  be deleted.

Or I may have rules a, b, c, d and e that respectively regenerate files a, b, c, d, e. 

If files b and d are deleted how do I prevent rules c and e from rerunning?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... I'm not sure if this is a bug, or intentional, or me missing something.

You can re-run only up to rule (or file) `b` with:

```
snakemake -j 1 -- b
```

After that, on re-running the all pipeline you get:

```
snakemake -p -j 1 
Building DAG of jobs...
Nothing to be done (all requested files are present and up to date).
Complete log: .snakemake/log/2023-06-23T153605.565616.snakemake.log
```

which seems to be what you want. However, this is an odd behavior since you get in state where file `b` is newer than file `c` even if file `c` depends on `b`, so I would say that requested files are present but they are *not* up to date.

One a second thought, this may be due to https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2011